# Element with directive doesn't $compile properly in unit test

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, karma-jasmine, angularjs-compile

My directive runs fine in the browser. It's just the unit test I can't seem to get working. The directive creates a simple slider, and sets a few values on the scope, including `min`.

In the unit test, $compile(element) seems to just wrap it in jqlite without doing anything else with it. Well, it also gives it a scope apparently, but there's nothing on the scope. The template also hasn't been applied.

My unit test:

```
describe('Given the slider directive', function () {

beforeEach(function() {
    module('app');
});

beforeEach(inject(function($httpBackend){
    // necessary because .whenGET().passThrough() doesn't seem to work
    $httpBackend.whenGET('partials/slider.html').respond('<div class="slider horizontal">'+
        '<div class="min">{{min}}</div>'+
        '<div class="max">{{max}}</div>'+
        '<a slider-handle class="handle" ng-class="{focus: focus}"'+
        'role="slider"'+
        'aria-valuemin="{{min}}" aria-valuemax="{{max}}" aria-valuenow="{{slider.value}}" aria-labelledby="{{id}}-label" aria-controls="{{id}}-value"'+
        'tabindex="0"'+
        'ng-keydown="handleKeyDown($event)" ng-keypress="handleKeyPress($event)"'+
        'ng-focus="handleFocus($event)" ng-blur="handleBlur($event)"'+
        'ng-mousedown="handleMouseDown($event)"'+
        'ng-style="{\'left\': slider.left}"></a>'+
        '<div ng-style="{\'left\': slider.left}" ng-show="showVals" id="{{id}}-value" class="slider-value" role="presentation">{{slider.value}}</div>'+
    '</div>');
}));

it('should compile and set the scope correctly', inject(function($compile, $rootScope) {
    var element = $compile('<div slider min="6" max="18" step="1" ng-model="value"></div>')($rootScope);
    $rootScope.$digest();

    var iScope = element.scope();

    iScope.$digest();

    console.log(iScope);
    console.log(iScope.min);
    console.log(element.html());
    console.log(element);

    expect(element.html()).toContain("6");
    expect(element.find('div[class=min]').html()).toBe(6);
    expect(iScope.min).toBe(6);

}));
});
```

The console output of this is:

```
Scope{$id: '00T', $$childTail: null, $$childHead: null, $$prevSibling: null, $$nextSibling: null, $$watchers: null, $parent: null, $$phase: null, $root: Scope{$id: '00T', $$childTail: null, $$childHead: null, $$prevSibling: null, $$nextSibling: null, $$watchers: null, $parent: null, $$phase: null, $root: Scope{$id: ..., $$childTail: ..., $$childHead: ..., $$prevSibling: ..., $$nextSibling: ..., $$watchers: ..., $parent: ..., $$phase: ..., $root: ..., this: ..., $$destroyed: ..., $$asyncQueue: ..., $$postDigestQueue: ..., $$listeners: ..., $$isolateBindings: ..., safeApply: ...}, this: Scope{$id: ..., $$childTail: ..., $$childHead: ..., $$prevSibling: ..., $$nextSibling: ..., $$watchers: ..., $parent: ..., $$phase: ..., $root: ..., this: ..., $$destroyed: ..., $$asyncQueue: ..., $$postDigestQueue: ..., $$listeners: ..., $$isolateBindings: ..., safeApply: ...}, $$destroyed: false, $$asyncQueue: [], $$postDigestQueue: [], $$listeners: Object{}, $$isolateBindings: Object{}, safeApply: function (a) { ... }}, this: Scope{$id: '00T', $$childTail: null, $$childHead: null, $$prevSibling: null, $$nextSibling: null, $$watchers: null, $parent: null, $$phase: null, $root: Scope{$id: ..., $$childTail: ..., $$childHead: ..., $$prevSibling: ..., $$nextSibling: ..., $$watchers: ..., $parent: ..., $$phase: ..., $root: ..., this: ..., $$destroyed: ..., $$asyncQueue: ..., $$postDigestQueue: ..., $$listeners: ..., $$isolateBindings: ..., safeApply: ...}, this: Scope{$id: ..., $$childTail: ..., $$childHead: ..., $$prevSibling: ..., $$nextSibling: ..., $$watchers: ..., $parent: ..., $$phase: ..., $root: ..., this: ..., $$destroyed: ..., $$asyncQueue: ..., $$postDigestQueue: ..., $$listeners: ..., $$isolateBindings: ..., safeApply: ...}, $$destroyed: false, $$asyncQueue: [], $$postDigestQueue: [], $$listeners: Object{}, $$isolateBindings: Object{}, safeApply: function (a) { ... }}, $$destroyed: false, $$asyncQueue: [], $$postDigestQueue: [], $$listeners: Object{}, $$isolateBindings: Object{}, safeApply: function (a) { ... }}
undefined
''
{0: <div slider="" min="6" max="18" step="1" ng-model="value" class="ng-scope"></div>, length: 1}
```

I've got a [JSFiddle with the entire (slightly cleaned up) code](http://jsfiddle.net/QGmCF/32/), but there it mysteriously doesn't even get past the $compile, which is not the same problem I have locally. Not sure if the JSFiddle is any use, because now I've got two mysterious problems instead of one.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Months of no answer or comments while I work on other stuff, and now I found the answer. It's really simple:

```
$httpBackend.flush();
```

When you use `$httpBackend.whenGET()` in a unit test, you always need to flush. So when you test a directive with a templateUrl, you need to flush() after you $compile().

I hope this is useful to someone out there.

Comment: Why should we do flush?

Comment: Because a GET doesn't immediately return. It's asynchronous, and to allow you to work with that in unit tests, you need to flush explicitly when you want the AJAX call to return. Without it, naive linear tests would be slightly easier, but it wouldn't be possible to test for problems caused be the asynchronicity you'll experience in production.

Comment: I suspect you need "flush()" only because you're using "whenGET()" (to get the directive's HTML), but not necessarily because you're testing a directive with a templateUrl. In my case I have all of my html templates preprocessed and stored in a $templateCache so "httpBackend.flush()" throws "Error: No pending request to flush !"